# Does wrapping lock into scope change when lock will be released?

Tags: rust, premature-optimization

In code

```rust
fn do_something_under_lock(some_bool_mutex: &Mutex<bool>) {
    do_something_before_lock();

    let some_bool = some_bool_mutex.lock().unwrap();
    do_something_with_some_bool(some_bool);

    do_something_after_lock();
}
```

will lock be released only after `do_something_after_lock();`?(or maybe compiler can prove that we don't need long lock time and decrease it?)

If lock will be released only after `do_something_after_lock();`, can we release lock earlier by wrapping `lock()` into own scope, like

```rust
fn do_something_under_lock_in_scope(some_bool_mutex: &Mutex<bool>) {
    do_something_before_lock();

    {
        let some_bool = some_bool_mutex.lock().unwrap();
        do_something_with_some_bool(some_bool);
    }

    do_something_after_lock();
}
```

Is wrapping into scope the best way to tell compiler what we want, or should we use some other way, like `drop` or something?

Comment: I'd say either worked and which ever makes the code clearest for the particular case should be favoured. In this case `drop(some_bool)` would release the lock.

Comment: Drop order is guaranteed in Rust, so the compiler cannot arbitrarily decide to drop something earlier. Wrapping the lock in a scope or manually dropping it does essentially the same thing (barring any other effects the nested scope might have).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lock will be released after `do_something_after_lock()`. This is considered observable behavior, and therefore, the compiler is not allowed to change that.

Wrapping the lock in scope and using `drop()` are both fine. I prefer the `drop()` version, but this is subjective. One thing that is important to note, however, is that in async functions the lock is considered alive even if you `drop()` it (it will be released, but the compiler will still consider its type as part of the generator type), so if the lock must not be held across `.await` points (for example because it is not `Send`), you must use a block and `drop()` is not enough. For instance, the following code errs:

```rust
async fn foo(mutex: &Mutex<i32>) {
    let _guard = mutex.lock().unwrap();
    drop(_guard);
    
    tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
}

tokio::spawn(foo(mutex));
```

You need to use a block:

```rust
async fn foo(mutex: &Mutex<i32>) {
    {
        let _guard = mutex.lock().unwrap();
    }
    
    tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
}

tokio::spawn(foo(mutex));
```

[This is expected to improve in future Rust versions](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/69663).